# Configuring a style for every chapter

Tags: sectioning, chapters, books, book-design

I'm creating a book in LaTeX and I'm creating a lot of duplicated formatting of the following nature:

```
\begin{chapter}
\begin{fullwidth}
\begin{LARGE}
```

......

```
\end{LARGE}
\end{fullwidth}
\end{chapter}
```

Is there a way of either:

- Re-wrapping the *\chapter* command to automagically include those tags, or
- Configuring a class-level style for *chapter* objects? (similarly to how one might in CSS?)

Comment: why do you have those commands at all? simply delete the `fullwidth` and `LARGE` environments and set up the required font and page size in the preamble as normal.

Comment: also note that you have to be very careful if you use a size command as an environment, make sure you always leave a blank line before `\end{LARGE}` or the line spacing will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks for those pointers! I'm editing [this template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/book-design-inspired-by-edward-tufte/gcfbtdjfqdjh), which doesn't seem very transparent for editing settings in the environment.

Comment: just out `\LARGE` in the preamble and text will go large but do you really want the body text to be larger than the text of your headings??? and similarly you can use `geometry` package or direct setting of `\textwidth`  to set the page size once for the book, there is no reason to  have wide text on everything except a chapter heading.